# SIPp REGISTER Scenario

Tags: ubuntu, sipp

I am completely new to Network and SIPp. I just installed SIPp in my ubuntu. I tested the first scenario given in the website: http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Using+SIPp

Here is the commands I used:

```
# ./sipp -sn uas
# ./sipp -sn uac 127.0.0.1
```

This creates a server and client and I can see the data traffic. However this shows me an INVITE scenario as below:

```
SIPp UAC            Remote
    |(1) INVITE         |
    |------------------>|
    |(2) 100 (optional) |
    |<------------------|
    |(3) 180 (optional) |
    |<------------------|
    |(4) 200            |
    |<------------------|
    |(5) ACK            |
    |------------------>|
    |                   |
    |(6) PAUSE          |
    |                   |
    |(7) BYE            |
    |------------------>|
    |(8) 200            |
    |<------------------|
```

But I need to see a REGISTER scenario as follows:

```
REGISTER ---------->
         200 <----------
         200 <----------
      INVITE ---------->
         100 <----------
         180 <----------
         403 <----------
         200 <----------
         ACK ---------->
             [  5000 ms]
         BYE ---------->
         200 <----------
```

I guess this is kind of a silly question but I have limited understanding of this topic. So I will be happy if you help me to get the result I want.
Thanks, Enes

Answer (score 0):

You can find scenario in below link.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeevan449/sipp-samples/master/uac-auth.xml
```

Comment: Just a note that I had an issue with this scenario on some servers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262689/sipp-keeps-resending-message/61262690